# How to get Windows 8.1 edition when installed on Parallels Desktop

Tags: windows, upgrade, boot-camp, windows-10, parallels

I know that one usually can lookup an installed edition of Windows 8.1 in System dialog. My Windows was installed with Parallels Desktop into a Boot Camp to support both loading scenarios, as a Guest and as a Host via Boot Camp.

Now I want to upgrade Windows to Windows 10 and I need to know which version of Windows 8.1 I am currently running, so that an upgrade would allow me to keep installed applications intact.

When I try to lookup my edition in system - it's not really helpful, it shows nothing:

[image]

How do I determine which Edition of Windows 10 I need to be able to upgrade?

Answer (score 0):

Running this in cmd.exe:

```
slmgr.vbs /dli
```

is the only way to see the edition of windows installed on boot camp via Parallels Desktop.